# interpret the function of summarize and group_by through the following two examples

Tags: group-by, summarize

I still don't quite understand the usage of summarize and group_by.Can you interpret the function of summarize and group_by through the following two examples
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2NDi.png)

[I still don't quite understand the usage of summarize and group_by.Can you interpret the function of summarize and group_by through the two examples？(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzLrc.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.